# Creating a database with EF6 SQL Server CE Code First crashing

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, code-first, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am seeing this error when I run my app

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbDispatchers.get_Connection()'.]
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 timeOut, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +0
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +75
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +132
```

Code:

```
var db = new AuditDb();
db.Database.CreateIfNotExists(); // blows up! 
or
db.Set<CampaignAudit>().Find(0); // same error
```

References:

```
EntityFramework:                  6.0.0.0
EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact: 6.0.0.0
System.Data:                      4.0.0.0
System.Data.SqlServerCe:          4.0.0.0
```

Context:

```
[DbConfigurationType("MvcTest.Data.AuditDBConfiguration, MvcTest")]
public class AuditDb : DbContext
{
    // tried this approach as well:
    // static AuditDb() { Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AuditDb>()); }
    public AuditDb() : base ("Name=AuditDB"){}
    public DbSet<CampaignAudit> Audits { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {

        Map<CampaignAudit>(builder);
        ...
}
```

DBConfiguration:

```
public class AuditDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public AuditDBConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(
            SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
            SqlCeProviderServices.Instance
        );
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(
            new SqlCeConnectionFactory(SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName)
        );
    }
}
```

Web.Config:

```
<add name="AuditDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=C:\logs\GroundAuditDb.sdf" />

<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
</providers>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Can't find much about this error. Seems that a connection property is missing on some object, or in some config, or some component I am using is incorrect version.

**update**

this is pretty crazy.. I've re-created the solution on another machine (windows 7 sp1 with VS 2013) and got all the nuget projects from scratch.

I bypassed database create problem by creating the database manually, but now started seeing this error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AlterTableOperation' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

so tried enabling migrations:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcTest.Data.AuditDb
```

which is throwing:

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.EntityMappingConfiguration`1.MapInheritedProperties()
```

it has been a stream of errors with no end in sight..

has anyone been able to make EF 6 work with SQL CE Code First approach??

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Data.Entity (you should not) ?

Comment: I do not. I do have a reference to System.Web.Entity

Comment: You need to remove/update that, it is the old EntityDataSource control

Comment: I removed that reference. didn't have any effect. Are you sure that is the cause? System.Data is 4.0.0.0

Comment: i got REALLY hopeful there for a second.. noticed that my framework was 4.5, and switched it to 4.5.1 on the project properties.. but that didn't resolve this issue :/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in my Solution. The problem was that I had different versions of EntityFramework in different projects in the solution. My recommendation is that you remove the EntityFramework dll from all the projects, remove the line about it from the packages.config and then reinstall using the "Install-Package EntityFramework" nuget command. Good luck!

Comment: I am using a single project solution. I also verified that the version is correct in my runtime bin

Comment: also i did mention that I did a fresh install on another computer.

Comment: I wasn't using SQL CE, but a normal sql server database. What's happening to you could be caused by the slow drop of support for sql CE from Microsoft. I looked for your error and saw a suggestion that I skipped: EntityFramework.SqlServer. Add this dll to your project any try again :(